# Implementing Extended Euclid Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, computer-science

Why is the following implementation of the [Extended Euclid Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) failing?

```
def extended_euclid(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return {a, 1, 0}

    d1,x1,y1 = extended_euclid(b, a % b)
    d = d1
    x = y1
    y = x1 - math.floor(a/b) * y1
    return {d, x, y}
```

Comment: Can you please define *failing*?

Comment: I'm getting wrong results.

Comment: Have you tried to use a *debugger* to figure out what is going wrong ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're returning a set?  You realized that it is an unordered data type, right?

Comment: @ChrisMueller, thank you! You could write it as an answer so I would approved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the implementation found in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm , looks similar to your's one.

```
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, x, y = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, y - (b // a) * x, x)
```

Comment: Thanks Václav Struhár!

Comment: Glad that it helped :) Would you mind to mark this answer as the solution? Thanks. @OliOliver

Answer (score 1):

```
def extended_euclid(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a, 1, 0

    d1,x1,y1 = extended_euclid(b, a % b)
    d = d1
    x = y1
    y = x1 - math.floor(a/b) * y1
    return d, x, y
```

remove `{}` from your return.
take a look at `d1,x1,y1 = extended_euclid(b, a % b)`, you don't have enough values to unpack if you keep `{}` in `return`.