# How to find the multiples of two numbers whose sum is a specific number

Tags: algorithm, performance, math

Suppose you have three numbers **A**, **B**, and **C**.

You need to find two numbers x,y such that
**A** * x + **B** * y = **C** *where x,y >= 1*

I want to know if there is a better and fast way or algorithm for this.

What I'm doing now is:

```
int maxFacA = C/A;
int maxFacB = C/B;
for (int i=1;i<=maxFacA;i++)
{
    for (int j=1;j<=maxFacB;j++)
    {
         if (A*i+B*j==C)
              //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: homeworks? :-) http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53211.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Extended Euclid Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978574/implementing-extended-euclid-algorithm)

Comment: You might want to mention that you're talking about *integers*.

Comment: If the variables involved are integers, this is an example of a Diophantine equation; a web search should turn up a lot of material related to that.

Comment: Is it a question from a code contest or online judge. ? Can you provide a link ? I would like to validate my answer.

Comment: You don't need the inner loop, just check if `(C - i * A) % B == 0`. It's faster but not the best way to do it.